# visualvm profiles jvm heap found int array takes huge memory

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm, heap-memory, visualvm

I have a Spring boot program using OpenJdk (jdk1.8) running at server, consuming about 200 or 300 million data from kafka and write to csv files each day. Less than 2 hours after starts up, it using more than 6GB memory. So I dump heap using jmap histo. And find that int[] array using 2.6GB and byte[] array using 1.3GB.
[image]
But I defined neither int[] nor byte[] in my project. I'm using spring kafka(org.springframework.kafka, version2.3.3) consume kafka message, opencsv(com.opencsv, version4.6) write csv.

Any one knows the reason?

Below is part of my code:

```
public <T> Boolean parseDataToFile(String filePath, List<T> data) throws IOException, CsvDataTypeMismatchException, CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException {
    if (data == null || data.size() <= 0) {
        return false;
    }
    File file = new File(filePath);
    //创建父目录
    boolean mkdirs = file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    Writer writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(filePath, true);
        StatefulBeanToCsv beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer).withThrowExceptions(false).withSeparator(',').build();
        beanToCsv.write(data);
        return true;
    } finally {
        if (writer != null) {
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Addtion: at Instance view, most(more than 90%) of them are none-used([retained size](https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/sizes.jsp) are 0), so it can be GCed? But why not? What are these int[] byte[] data?
[image]

Comment: Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/heapdump.html ("Instances View") and try to find out which GC roots reference those arrays

Comment: @JurajMartinka most of them are not using instance. I added a pic to show.

Comment: If they aren't used they should be GCed at some point. You might want to check if full gc has been done before the heap dump was collected (which is often done but tools have an option to avoid that).

Comment: @JurajMartinka Yes, it should so, but this program just occupyed more and more memory. 6GB used when I dump heap, but now 12GB after running half a month. I don't understand.

Comment: You could use tools like `jcmd` to quickly look at some GC related statistics. From high-level, the current sizes of Young and Old generations and then class histogram. It's a bit limited on JDK 8 (**you should really upgrade** to at least JDK 11) but it's still useful. Run `jcmd <PID>` to check which commands are supported. On My system I'd use `GC.heap_info`, `GCc.class_histogram` and maybe `GC.class_stats`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @AlBlue and @JurajMartinka. I analysed the byte[] array and int[] array and found part of the answer.
The int[] array which have 166921 instance, using 2.6GB memory(57.3%). Most of them have no reference:
[image]
Some of them are used by kafka:
[image]
Meanwhile spring boot loader:
[image]

On the other hand, the byte[] array have 39400 instance, using 1.3GB memory(28.8%). Most of them are kafka data:
[image]
Some are other referred dependencies:
[image]

The real memory using by live objects are not big. MAT(The Eclipse Memory Analyzer tool) shows that only 43.6M are occupied.
[image]

Yet, there are still many questions needs to find out. Such as when to GC, where is netty used, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The occurrence of byte or char arrays in a program is typically due to Strings used by the code. You should be able to see if they are being referenced by String objects by looking at the memory dominators in MAT.

The use of int arrays is far less common in general code in the JDK so you would need to find where they are being dominated from to find out.

However note that in both cases, what you are directly using in your code is not relevant; the usage is most likely from your dependencies under the covers. Whether it’s the JVM classes or some other cache mechanism is likely to depend on where the objects are being referred from, so the next stage is to use the tooling to find that out.